# How To use Query Join + Insert the value

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter-3

My Model

```
public function insertJoin($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert($this->_table, $data);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('incoming');
    $this->db->join('tb_printoutbarcode', 'incoming.lot_numberI = tb_printoutbarcode.lot_number');
}
```

My Controller

```
public function process_save()
{
    $data = [
        'lot_numberI' => $this->input->post('lot_numberI'),
        'receive_date' => $this->input->post('receive_date'),
        'part_number' => $this->input->post('part_number'),
        'qty_in' => $this->input->post('qty_in'),
        'balance' => $this->input->post('balance'),
        'remark' => $this->input->post('remark'),
        'txndate' => $this->input->post('txndate'),
        'userid' => $this->input->post('userid'),
    ];
    if ($this->m_incoming->insertJoin($data)) {
        redirect('incoming');
    } else {
        redirect('incoming');
    }
}
```

I want to make an input with only the "lot number" code and all the data on the typed lot number is taken. I've tried and it works but the data doesn't appear / null in the table.
lot number attribute =  is a part_number, qty, balance and other, i want to make all attribute join by part number and insert to new table incoming with attribute just input by lot_number, it's posibble ?
Am Using Codeigniter 3 .
[image: SS Table Mysql]

[image: SS my Table in Codeigniter 3]

Comment: Anything else after **return**: `return $this->db->insert($this->_table, $data);` will not be processed

Comment: `public function insertJoin($data)
 {
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('incoming');
  $this->db->join('tb_printoutbarcode', 'incoming.lot_numberI = tb_printoutbarcode.lot_number');
  $this->db->insert($this->_table, $data);
 }` like this sir ? it works but in an empty mysql table, only lot_number is added.

Answer (score 0):

1. I see the **part_number**, **qty_in** and **balance** fields are null, please go to the source code of the form **in view** file where you entered these values. Check the `name` attributes are matches with $_POST array indexes in Controller.
2. You call your insert function:

   ```
    public function process_save()
    {
        (...)
        if ($this->m_incoming->insertJoin($data)){
            redirect('incoming');
        }
        (...)
    }
   ```

So far OK, but now you need to separate the **select** from the **insertJoin** function and move the select to the function which appears the **incoming** page